# std::sort fail to work when input vector has called reserve

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, std

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>


int main()
{
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-1.0, 1.0);
std::vector<float> s;
s.reserve(10);
for (int i=0; i< 10; ++i) s[i] = dis(gen);
for (int i=0; i< 10; ++i) std::cout << s[i] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
for (int i=0; i< 10; ++i) std::cout << s[i] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

the output is:
0.459711 0.0240773 -0.395009 0.574655 -0.244166 -0.343489 -0.520125 0.746452 0.858716 0.765223 
0.459711 0.0240773 -0.395009 0.574655 -0.244166 -0.343489 -0.520125 0.746452 0.858716 0.765223 
std::sort fail to work!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.reserve` doesn't resize the vector, so doing `s[i]` is undefined behavior. You must use `.resize` instead or use `push_back` to insert elements.

After `.reserve` `.begin()` is still equal to `.end()` (as in an empty vector) which means `std::sort` will have no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

`reserve` does not automatically put your vector internal size to what you specify. All it does is change the capacity of its internal array to 10 while its size remains unchanged.

Calling `s[i]` while `i` is larger than or equal to vector's size will give undefined behaviour.

To fix this, change
`s[i] = dis(gen);`
to
`s.push_back(dis(gen));`